# Bootstrap glyphicons with virtual host

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to make `glyphicons` work with my local project!

i have created a virtual host called `backend.mvc`

now when ever i try to use `glyphicons` i get the following error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://backend.mvc/site/resources/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
    glyphi...ar.woff
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://backend.mvc/site/resources/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
```

however the path exists execpt from the `http://` so my question is how can avoid  this and make the glyphicons work?

**edit**

Ive added the following to my head:

```
    <link type="application/font-woff">
    <link type="application/vnd.ms-fontobject">
    <link type="application/x-font-ttf">
    <link type="font/opentype">
```

However this did nothing :(

**Update**

Using apache

Also please note that this is for web and NOT mobile!

Comment: what server technology are you using? Apache/PHP, IIS/ASP.NET, etc.?

Comment: well, one solution, although not the best might be to use the CDN version of bootstrap http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that they're not in the incorrect place, then the most common cause I come across for problems like this when it comes to serving web-fonts is that the server isn't configured to serve the correct mime-type for the files.

According to [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) these are the mime-types that you should be using when serving web fonts:

**woff:** `application/font-woff`

**eot:** `application/vnd.ms-fontobject`

**ttf & ttc:** `application/x-font-ttf`

**otf:** `font/opentype`

Comment: ive added the following to my head:
        <link type="application/font-woff">
        <link type="application/vnd.ms-fontobject">
        <link type="application/x-font-ttf">
        <link type="font/opentype">

Answer (score 0):

The fonts directory should be in the same dir as the css directory by default, not in the css subdirectory
Also check your paths in the bootstrap.css